# Is there a way to use BehaviourSubject accross modules?

Tags: angular, angular5, behaviorsubject

I would like to use the `BehaviourSubject` to share data between two components from two different modules. How do I accomplish this?

**CurrenciesModule**

```
 export class CurrenciesComponent implements OnInit {
   defaultCurrency: CurrencyModel;     

 constructor(private coreServ:CoreService) {    
   }     
      ngOnInit() {     
     this.coreServ.DefaultCurrency.subscribe((val) => {
       this.defaultCurrency = val;
       console.log({ currNewDefault: this.defaultCurrency });
          });
      }

 selectCurrency(currency: CurrencyModel) {
  this.coreServ.changeDefaultCurrency(currency);
 }
 }
```

**SharedModule**

```
  export class ChooseCurrencyComponent implements OnInit {

  defaultCurrency: CurrencyModel;
  Currencies: CurrencyModel[];

  constructor(private coreServ:CoreService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.coreServ.DefaultCurrency.subscribe((val) => {
     this.defaultCurrency = val;
     console.log({ chooseNewDefault: this.defaultCurrency });
  });
//this.readMany();
  }
  selectCurrency(currency:CurrencyModel) {
this.coreServ.changeDefaultCurrency(currency);
   }
```

and the **CoreService**

```
 @Injectable()
 export class CoreService {

   private defaultCurrency = new BehaviorSubject<CurrencyModel>(null);
   DefaultCurrency = this.defaultCurrency.asObservable();

   changeDefaultCurrency(currency: CurrencyModel) {
     this.defaultCurrency.next(currency);
   }
 }
```

finally the model

```
   export class CurrencyModel {
     public ID: string;
     public Name: string;

     public Rates: [{key:string}];
     private form: FormGroup;

     constructor() {
     }
   }
```

Comment: If you need to share data between components/modules use a service.

Comment: Where you declare the service (in which module.ts)? You must declare only in a unique module.ts. Then, your code must be work. NOTE: Where you call the functions changeDefaultCurrency?

Comment: @Eliseo in my component html I have `<button (click)='selectCurrency(currency)'></button>` where `currency` is an instance of `CurrencyModel`

Comment: @Bellash, then if the service is declared in a only module.ts, your code must be work :(

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know it is not possible to do it directly, but you could just use a "custom event hadler" and build something like:
Service:

```
onCurrencyChange(callbackFN: (currency: CurrencyModel) => void): void {
 someEventArray.push(callbackFN);
}
```

then if you change the default currency do:

```
someEventArray.forEach(event => event(newDefaultCurrency));
```

Comment: Richard, not, it's not necesary